# Como obtener ultimo registro | mongoDB | Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto y tengo una duda muy simple, si tengo en DB unos cuantos registros, por ejemplo estos:

```
{
 { 'name':'nombre1',
   'edad':'22'
 },
 { 'name':'nombre2',
   'edad':'23'
 },
 { 'name':'nombre3',
   'edad':'24'
 },
}
```

Como puedo hacer para seleccionar el ultimo registro, que en este caso seria el que tiene de nombre 'nombre 3'.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ordenar los registros según su orden de inserción usando [Natural Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order) y especificando que vengan desde el más reciente al más antiguo

```
db.micoleccion.find().sort({$natural:-1});
```

Si quieres el último registro, sería

```
db.micoleccion.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);
```

**Ojo**: Si usas el storage engine MMAP1, el orden natural considera que [actualizar un registro existente lo convierte en el más reciente](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#mmapv1).